# Node.js Using WDC 3.0 - adding an attribute of content-type

Tags: node.js, rest, tableau-desktop

I am using the taco toolkit using OAuth to get a connector for an API.  I am able to build my project from the boilerplate and I authenticate with my site credentials but tableau throws an error of a missing or incorrect content type.
[image]

I followed this tutorial to build my project.
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/webdataconnector/en-us/docs/wdc_create_oauth_connector.html
I also went through the sample tutorial here
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/webdataconnector/en-us/index.html
There are a few spots I have attempted to add the content-type attribute in the config files but receive errors
Error: An invalid connector.json was found at: C:\Users\user\my-oauth-connector2\connector\connector.json
Errors: [{"instancePath":"","schemaPath":"#/additionalProperties","keyword":"additionalProperties","params":{"additionalProperty":"headers"},"message":"must NOT have additional properties"}]

I am pretty new to building this connector and I found some additional information that might help......
Additional info and reference data:
https://github.com/tableau/webdataconnector/wiki/Preview:-WDC-3.0
https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_wdc_connector_sdk.htm
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/webdataconnector/en-us/docs/wdc_dev_considerations.html